# How to change different subscription dates into same date in Chargebee?

Tags: subscription, billing, chargebee

There are 3 subscriptions for a customer. Two subscriptions have billing date of 7th of each month and one subscription has 26th of each month as billing date. I would like billing date of all three subscriptions to be 26th of the month. Is it possible to make this change in Chargebee? and How?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do this via UI or API. Please check if this support article helps — https://support.chargebee.com/support/solutions/articles/246681-changing-the-billing-date-to-a-different-date

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).